# Linux is skipping over my else statement when running bash script?

Tags: bash

So I need to have it say the person is not in the class. It seems like it is skipping my else statement. Is something wrong?

```
if [ $# == 1 ]; then

    if  grep "$1" /acct/common/CSCE215 | cut -d ',' -f1-3 | tr ',' ' '; then
    true

    else
            echo "Sorry that person is not in CSCE215 this semester"
    fi

else
    echo "Command line arguments are not equal to 1"
    echo "$#"
fi
```

Comment: Which `else` statement? What is the value of `$#` and `$1`?

Comment: One way to troubleshoot is add set -x to the beginning of the script and it will show you the trace of your script

Comment: It is skipping the nested else statement, $# should be 1, and $1 is a username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exit code of the piped commands is the exit code of the last one (`tr` in your case, which is always `0`)

Use `set -o pipefail` option in your script to break piping if one of the commands failed.

Example:

```
$ echo foo | grep bar | tr o a ; echo $?
0
$ set -o pipefail ; echo foo | grep bar | tr o a ; echo $?
1
```

So your script could be:

```
set -o pipefail

if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
    if  grep "$1" /acct/common/CSCE215 | cut -d ',' -f1-3 | tr ',' ' '; then
        true
    else
        echo "Sorry that person is not in CSCE215 this semester"
    fi
else
    echo "Command line arguments are not equal to 1"
    echo "$#"
fi
```

PS: Use `set +o pipefail` to restore the usual behavior.